# How update kubernetes v1.10.8 and kismatic v1.12.0 to last with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes (v1.10.8) installed on my cloud by kismatic (v1.12.0). How I can update kubernetes to the latest version with `kubeadm`?

Answer (score 1):

With such version difference - we currently have [v1.23](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.23.md#v1231) ([see official supported releases](https://kubernetes.io/releases/)) - I would consider creating the cluster from the beginning.

If this is not possible, you should upgrade them step by step (from version to version). [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/) you can find guide that will help to upgrade kubeadm clusters.
A link to older versions you can find [here](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/), but

> ***NOTE***:
> Kubernetes v1.19 documentation is no longer actively maintained. The version you are currently viewing is a static snapshot.

However, you have to have in mind that upgrading through so many versions can cause other issues, so I recommend using the first option.